# How to get entered text from a textbox in Selenium

Tags: selenium, junit, grid, webdriver, testng

I enter a value in TextBox or a Combobox, and would like to retrieve the value I have just entered. I see that Selenium Weblement method `getText()` doesn't retrieve the value, it seems the entered text doesn't get pushed into DOM.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `getText()` method is for retrieving a text node between element tags for example:

```
<p>Something</p>
```

`getText()` will return "Something"

In a textbox typed text goes into the value attribute so you can try something like:

```
findElement(By.id("someid")).getAttribute("value");
```

`ComboBox` is a bit different.  But if you're using the `Select` object you can use the method:

```
Select selectItem = new Select(findElement(By.id("someid")));
selectItem.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Comment: Thanks bob, it works as expected. Why using Firebug the entered text is not getting updated in the value attribute ?

Comment: Just to be clear, it has be to getAttribute("value"), lower case. Not "Value". Which is what i got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getValue` if it is a Text Field or Dropdown box

```
String lastname=selenium.getValue("//*[@id='lastName']");
System.out.println(lastname);
```

Comment: I do not see that function, do you have documentation on it?

Answer (score 0):

**This is how we can fetch the text written in a textbox using Selenium + Python:**

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Type_Xpath_Here").get_attribute('value')
print(text)
```