# Vaadin - get input element value from DOM

Tags: java, selenium, input, vaadin

I want to test my vaadin component automatically but to do that I have to somehow get and set value into corresponding element. Normally in HTML DOM you see it like this:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
```

but in vaadin:

```
<input type="text" class="v-textfield v-widget v-has-width" id="first-name-text-field" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-40" tabindex="0" style="width: 250px;">
```

yet this element could contain the same text as the textarea above.

I am missing something and cannot find where I should get/set methods. Googling didn't help, official documentation didn't seem to hahve anything on the matter. At this point I'm confused.

ps: if it helps I want to test it with Selenium, but I think it's unrelated. I would like to answer any and all question that would point me to the right direction. Thanks.

pss: Maybe there actually is method in java-selenium to getValue() of element and I do not need this dom?

Comment: Best go via the ID `id="first-name-text-field"`

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood. I don't want to get some element (I can do that), but I want to put/get value into element. In vaadin element, for which I do not understand how it's values stored/retrieved.

Comment: You are using Selenium. I would guess it is just the same as without Vaadin: `driver.findElement(By.id("first-name-text-field")).sendKeys("test");`

Comment: Its input type text....

Comment: @SteffenHarbich yes, for inputing. How do i retrieve what's inside? i.e. getValue() or smth.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly. Do you want to retrieve value of the input text component during the Selenium test or during the runtime? I think Selenium expose api that can check whether the element contains certain value.

Comment: @Sarief should be `getText()` or `getAttribute("value")` on the `WebElement`. I guess the latter one will work.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich, getAttr by "value" actually worked. Don't know why I didn't find it by myself. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have set the ID to the component via [setId](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setId%28java.lang.String%29), you can use Selenium as usual. For text inputs you can then call

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your-id")).getAttribute("value")
```

to get the value entered by user. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990752/1063673) answer.